# Algorithm for border-zeroes and ones in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance, multidimensional-array

Consider a 2D array that I have named "zeroesAndOnes" that has a random length and width and that has also been randomly filled with zeroes and ones.

I want to know an algorithm that would count the number of zeroes that share a border with the ones in the array. Sharing a border in this case means that a zero in the array has at least 1 one above, below, the left, and/or the right of it, with no diagonal-direction checks.

If a zero is shared by multiple ones under these conditions above, then it should be counted as a duplicate zero and should not be added into the final result.

```java
//Test Arrays
int[][] nums1 = {
                 {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                 {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                };

int[][] nums2 = {
                 {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
                 {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                 {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                 {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
                };

//Method Definition
public static int borderZeros(int[][] nums) {
   int border = 0;
   //See instructions and examples above! I have defined a result variable called "border" to return when the procedure is defined according to the instructions above.
   //Should return the integer zero, if nums has a length <= 1 & width <= 1, as a base case.
   //Otherwise should return the number of zeroes bordering a one under the conditions described, with no duplicate zeroes.
}

//Driver Code
System.out.println(borderZeros(nums1));
System.out.println(borderZeros(nums2));
//Should print the integers 10 and 18 (I think!) respectively if coded properly.
//Should work for arrays of all sizes!
//No ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions!
```

The only thing I have done so far was to implement a nested for-loop that would check surrounding characters for zeroes if the element in the array concerned was one, but that has resulted in the out-of-bounds index exception, and trying to alleviate that exception has resulted in me not checking all the elements.

I need to find some way that I can get the algorithm without causing the exception and that I have checked for all elements in the array.

Any solution that works, preferably something that you think is *elegant*, *novel*, or *efficient*, would be greatly appreciated! I am very much a novice programmer, and I'm still learning. ;)

** ***Addendum*** **

Per Jim Mischel's advice, I have attached my really *dumb* code below. It currently does not account for duplicate zeroes, or the obvious array index exceptions, or the fact that I may not account for all the zeroes.

```java
public static int borderZeros(int[][] nums) {
  int border = 0;
  for (int r = 1; r < nums.length - 1; r++) {
    for (int c = 1; c < nums[r].length - 1; c++) {
      if (nums[r][c] == 1) {
        if (nums[r - 1][c] == 0) {
          border++;
        }
        if (nums[r][c - 1] == 0) {
          border++;
        }
        if (nums[r + 1][c] == 0) {
          border++;
        }
        if (nums[r][c + 1] == 0) {
           border++;
        }
      }
      else {
        continue;
      } 
    }
  }
  return border;
}
```

** ***End Addendum*** **

Comment: Show us your code that implements your algorithm. Otherwise we can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: @JimMischel I have attached my code, with minimal understanding on how to account for the edge cases, or if I am even approaching the problem correctly. I will eagerly await your answer regardless. ;)

Comment: What is the maximum size of your matrix?

Comment: @Holger Any 2D matrix of whatever dimensions are fine; there is no maximum limit to its size.

Comment: And the array elements have to be `int` despite being only `0` or `1`? Or is it possible to use a more compact data structure, i.e. to store one bit of information as just one bit?

Answer (score 0):

An "elegant" algorithm would be to use this convolution matrix and after that count the values < 0:

```
 0 -1  0
-1  4 -1 
 0 -1  0
```

Comment: How would you implement that in the code?

Comment: for each input value of your matrix (arrays) you multiply the center of the convolution matrix (4) with that value, and the value of the 8 surrounding cells of the convolution matrix with the value of the 8 surrounding cells of the input matrix. Add up all products to your output value (one output cell for each input cell).
In the end with this convolution matrix you count all cells that have a value < 0 - those are the "edge cells" you want to find. For the border of the matrix you have to take special care, take the input of the nearest neighbour as you don't want to count that as edge.

Comment: Just found that Wikipedia has an explanation that is a lot better than mine for understanding the principle of a [Discrete convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution)

Answer (score 0):

We can set this up as a graph theory problem. All the cells are nodes. Two nodes are joined by an edge if they differ (one is zero, the other is one). Keep one-nodes separate from zero-nodes.

Now you have a bipartite graph, since edges only exists between 0-nodes and 1-nodes. What you're looking for is this context is called a 'maximum bipartite matching' or a 'maximum matching in a bipartite graph.'

The advantage of setting this up as a bipartite matching problem is that it takes care of duplicate zero problem for you.

Comment: Thanks! Makes viewing the problem way easier now for some reason. :)